# Facebook fan page like count from a tab

Tags: facebook-like

How can I get the *like* count (new fans) of my Facebook fan page from a specific tab (application)?

Let us say my Facebook fan page has three tabs (hence three applications). How can I know how many *likes* was originated from each of these three tabs?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to count them yourself as the "like" action is being performed for the same object (page object).
Use this method and the JavaScript SDK to detect when a user "likes" the page.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
```

Taken from here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Once you detect the "like" you can post to your server and include the `app_id`.  Store this in your database and [hey-presto](http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/0/e/f/1194986747968776387abracadabra_jean_maurice_.svg.med.png) - per tab like counts :P